# Make regex allow letters, numbers and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, apex

I have search for a regex to not allow more that one space between words, and I get this:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$'
```

It's working, but I realize that is not accepting special characters, so I implemented:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&?!*%()\\-`.+,/\"]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&?!*%()\\-`.+,/\"]+)*$'
```

But it make me wonder if it has other formula so can i accepted all letters, numbers and all special characters, without having to write all the special characters.

Example:
'Test   Test'
If it has more than one spacing between words like this, the regex need to catch that.

Comment: Are you OK with more than one space that's not between words? It seems like the easiest way to handle this would be to reduce all 1+ spaces to 1 space.

Comment: What are some examples of spaces _not_ between words? The specification seems vague here. It seems like `/  /.test(foo)` should work to identify if there are two consecutive spaces anywhere, although we have both Java, JavaScript and apex tags, so I'm not sure what language we're in.

Comment: Thanks for response, I'm not using a language, I'm using validation rule from Salesforce, so I need to use regex for this

Answer (score 0):

If my regex is right, you should be able to use
`\S+ \S+`
'\S' is any char that isn't whitespace. All symbols and letters are included in '\S', and we have '+' for any 1 or more of those. Then with a single space in-between, it will only match words that have one space between them. However, make sure your careful if you are applying this to a big file. This will not check every word pair. If two words match with only one space, then they will be pulled, and the second word would not be tested against the second;

```
one two three
```

In this case, only `one two` would be grabbed, and three would never be checked with two because we found a match. An easier approach for making sure there arent doubble spaces could be to specifcially find all the doubble spaces in your text and deal with them how you must.